# How to find if a specific <div> has an <img> tag nested within it using Excel VBA?

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I'm extracting data from source using xmlHttp request and looking for a certain error where a specific `<div>` tag contains no data between the opening & closing tag. If the class name was unique, I could use `getElementsByClassName` to search, but the page I'm trying to access is using multiple `<div>` tags with the same class.

Example 1 (`<div>` without data):

```
<div class="text-right-image-left-container">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 imageleftpadding centered">

</div>
</div>
```

Example 2 (`<div>` with data):

```
<div class="text-right-image-left-container">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 imageleftpadding centered">
    <img alt="Testing" class="img-responsive lazy" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png" title="">
</div>
</div>
```

The 2nd example contains `<img>` within the div `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 imageleftpadding centered">`.

Is there a way to find all `<div>` with `class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 imageleftpadding centered"` and check whether they contain any data or none?

Comment: Can you share the URL and do all the divs of interest have the img tag inside?  And what values are you actually after?

Comment: EDIT: I can't share the exact url as it's intranet. By right all those divs with that specific class should follow with an img tag. So what i'm looking for is if any one of those divs missing the img tag inside. I'll look up for a similar page url with similar structure somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could gather all the divs with that class name and then loop testing if they have a child `img` tagged element. In my example, I print out the `outerHTML` of the elements which don't have the child `img`.

Sadly VBA implementation doesn't support the [:not CSS pseudo-class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) or you could simply have done `html.querySelectorAll(".col-xs-12.col-sm-6.imageleftpadding.centered:not(img)")`.

With XMLHTTP you would use the following:

```
Set html = New HTMLDocument
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", "URL", False
    .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
End With
Dim nodeList As Object, i As Long, ele As Object
Set nodeList = html.querySelectorAll(".col-xs-12.col-sm-6.imageleftpadding.centered")

For i = 0 To nodeList.Length - 1
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ele = nodeList.item(i).getElementsByTagName("img")
    If ele.Length = 0 Then Debug.Print nodeList.item(i).outerHTML
    On Error GoTo 0
Next i
```

Comment: I get an error when i run the above code "Sub or Function not defined" for GetHTMLFileContent

Comment: you can't run that function as it is to read html in from my desktop. You need to replace with the code at the bottom. I have edited.

Comment: I see how it works now. The result is closer to what i wanted. I'll explore & modify from here onward. Thanks a lot.

Comment: on a side note, when i run the code i do get a windows security warning "This page is accessing information that is not under its control...." Do you know why & is there a way to bypass / disable it? when i run the code on loop for multiple URL's i have to click Yes for each link.

Comment: I don't as I am not running via XMLHTTP. Worth checking on Stackoverflow/StackExchange to see if anyone else has had this issue.